# How to implement logic on list of dictionaries based on multiple key value pairings?

Tags: python, dictionary, if-statement

I have a list of dictionaries below:

```
d_dict = [
    {'Abs Diff': 10,'Difference':10, 'Component': 'Local Market', 'Id':'123', 'Name': 'LAT', 'Executor':'AB'}, 
    {'Abs Diff': 20,'Difference':20, 'Component': 'Local Market', 'Id':'123', 'Name': 'LAT', 'Executor':'B'},
    {'Abs Diff': 30,'Difference':-30, 'Component': 'Local Market', 'Id':'123', 'Name': 'LAT', 'Executor':'BA'},
    {'Abs Diff': 23,'Difference':23, 'Component': 'USD Market', 'Id':'456', 'Name': 'LAT', 'Executor':'CB'}, 
    {'Abs Diff': 25,'Difference':25, 'Component': 'USD Market', 'Id':'456', 'Name': 'LAT', 'Executor':'C'},
    {'Abs Diff': 48,'Difference':-48, 'Component': 'USD Market', 'Id':'456', 'Name': 'LAT', 'Executor':'CB'},
    {'Abs Diff': 5,'Difference':5, 'Component': 'Price', 'Id':'123', 'Name': 'LAT', 'Executor':'AB'}, 
    {'Abs Diff': 5,'Difference':5, 'Component': 'Price', 'Id':'123', 'Name': 'LAT', 'Executor':'B'},
    {'Abs Diff': 10,'Difference':-10, 'Component': 'Price', 'Id':'123', 'Name': 'LAT', 'Executor':'BA'}
    ]
```

My end goal is to have a dictionary that returns:

```
result = [
    {'Abs Diff': 10,'Difference':10, 'Component': 'Local Market', 'Id':'123', 'Name': 'LAT', 'Executor':'AB', 'Result':'Mismatched Executor'}, 
    {'Abs Diff': 20,'Difference':20, 'Component': 'Local Market', 'Id':'123', 'Name': 'LAT', 'Executor':'B', 'Result':'Mismatched Executor'},
    {'Abs Diff': 30,'Difference':-30, 'Component': 'Local Market', 'Id':'123', 'Name': 'LAT', 'Executor':'BA', 'Result':'Mismatched Executor'},
    {'Abs Diff': 23,'Difference':23, 'Component': 'USD Market', 'Id':'456', 'Name': 'LAT', 'Executor':'CB', 'Result':'Mismatched Executor'}, 
    {'Abs Diff': 25,'Difference':25, 'Component': 'USD Market', 'Id':'456', 'Name': 'LAT', 'Executor':'C', 'Result':'Mismatched Executor'},
    {'Abs Diff': 48,'Difference':-48, 'Component': 'USD Market', 'Id':'456', 'Name': 'LAT', 'Executor':'CB', 'Result':'Mismatched Executor'},
    {'Abs Diff': 5,'Difference':5, 'Component': 'Price', 'Id':'123', 'Name': 'LAT', 'Executor':'AB', 'Result':'Mismatched Executor'}, 
    {'Abs Diff': 5,'Difference':5, 'Component': 'Price', 'Id':'123', 'Name': 'LAT', 'Executor':'B', 'Result':'Mismatched Executor'},
    {'Abs Diff': 10,'Difference':-10, 'Component': 'Price', 'Id':'123', 'Name': 'LAT', 'Executor':'BA', 'Result':'Mismatched Executor'}
]
```

I want to implement a logic that goes:
if the Abs Diff is greater than 0 and if the component, id, name MATCH across multiple elements and if the sum of the differences across the same elements is less than 1 and the executor is different across those elements, return a new key value pairing "Result": "Mismatched"

I am having trouble visualizing how to scan through multiple dictionaries within the list and check for the matching component, ids, and names.

Comment: All your results say Mismatched

Comment: You can use itertools.groupby with a key that selects the elements that you want to be identical

Comment: @Barmar based on the logic, each one should be mismatched based on the groupings of component, id, and name (3 unique groupings over the 9 elements)

Comment: It would be helpful if your example also included cases where they aren't mismatched.

Answer (score 0):

Call `sum()` with a generator that finds all the dictionaries that match the criteria.

```
for i in d_dict:
    if i['Abs Diff'] > 0 and \
        sum(x['Difference'] for x in d_dict 
            if (x['Component'], x['Id'], x['Name']) == (i['Component'], i['Id'], i['Name']) and x['Executor'] != i['Executor']
        ) < 1:
        i['Result'] = 'Mismatched Executor'
```

Comment: This unfortunately does not account for all the elements in the dictionary.

Comment: Which ones doesn't it account for?

Comment: It sums all the dictionaries with the same component, id, and name and a different executor.

Comment: The result I see for a dictionary when running the above is 
{'Abs Diff': 30,
  'Difference': -30,
  'Component': 'Local Market',
  'Id': '123',
  'Name': 'LAT',
  'Executor': 'BA'}

no "result": "mismatched executor"

Answer (score 0):

Heres an example of how I would solve this problem

```
from operator import itemgetter

newdict = []
for i in d_dict:
    if(i['Abs Diff'] > 0):
        newdict.append(i)
newlist = sorted(newdict, key=itemgetter('Component'))         
for i in range(0,len(d_dict)-1):
    if(d_dict[i]['Component'] == d_dict[int(i+1)]['Component']):
        print("TRUE")
```

Comment: The grouping is by Component, Id, and Name.